# Python - excel export

Tags: python, pandas

I've got this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')  
workbook = writer.book
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='quotations',startrow=0 , startcol=0)
```

after running it, the following error shows up:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]`

Comment: read_html creates a list of dataframe objects. if you print len(df) what do you get? if its just 1, then you should change it to df[0].to_excel(...) and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`pandas.read_html` documentation:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) `Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.`

So, `df` is a list of dataframes. If you expect to only have one, it may be safe for you to use `df[0].to_excel...`

Answer (score 3):

`pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes, you need to use an indexer to get the first dataframe.

Use:

```
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```