# Get the previous and next page tables from pagination URL in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to iteratively crawler the tables from each page on this [website](http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894). With the code below I'm able to extract one page only:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894'
website_url = requests.get(url).text
#soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090632/python-excel-export
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df.head(5))
```

Output:

```
   序号  ...      竣工备案日期
0   1  ...  2020-01-23
1   2  ...  2020-01-23
2   3  ...  2020-01-23
3   4  ...  2020-01-23
4   5  ...  2020-01-23

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

Any ideas how could I get each page content by click next page button on the web? Thank you.

[image]

Full code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for page in range(1, 790):
    data = {
      'filter_LIKE_GCMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_JSDWMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_SGDWMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_BABH': '',
      'currentPage': page,
      'pageSize': '15',
      'OrderByField': '',
      'OrderByDesc': ''
    }

    website_url = requests.post('http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894', data = data).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090632/python-excel-export
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    print(df)
    dfs = pd.concat([df, dfs], sort = False)
print(dfs.columns)
dfs.to_excel('./test.xlsx', index = False)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-9f217cba563e>", line 28, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 987, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 815, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 404, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

ValueError: No tables found
```

Comment: Your URL: http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894 takes a `pageId` param. You have to determine the pageId for each page and concatinate it to form the URL for selected page from navigation

Comment: The `pageId` didn't change when I click to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data` below to get page by number and other parameters, using `POST`. Change `currentPage` number to go to the next or previous page. Using `td.Normal` css selector you can get total results.

```
data = {
  'filter_LIKE_GCMC': '',
  'filter_LIKE_JSDWMC': '',
  'filter_LIKE_SGDWMC': '',
  'filter_LIKE_BABH': '',
  'currentPage': '1',
  'pageSize': '15',
  'OrderByField': '',
  'OrderByDesc': ''
}

website_url = requests.post('http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894', data=data).text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do I need to use `for` loop for each page then concatenate dataframes?

Comment: Yes, you have to do `for` loop. I updated the answer, you can get total result and total pages count in the response body

Comment: Sorry, I have met a problem, for the last page, `pageSize` should be `2`, how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Do not have to change `pageSize`, change `currentPage` like 1, 2, 3...

Comment: I use a loop to iterate all pages, but I get `ValueError: No tables found`. Could you help? Please check updates of my question.

Comment: I tried with `currentPage=789`, no errors. The problem maybe in the response. You have to debug it, use `try/except` to catch the problem and check.

Comment: Ok, may I ask where I can get `data = {'filter_LIKE_GCMC': '', 'filter_LIKE_JSDWMC': '', 'filter_LIKE_SGDWMC': '', 'filter_LIKE_BABH': '', 'currentPage': '1', 'pageSize': '15', 'OrderByField': '', 'OrderByDesc': ''}`?

Comment: You can get headers and other details in Chrome DevTools Network Tab