# Exclude row without index and set another row as header in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I remove the first row from the following dataframe and set row of `index = 0` as header? Thank you.

```
     0     ...           8        ---> row without index to exclude which is header of current dataframe
0   id     ...          date      ---> row to set as header
1    1     ...      2020-01-23
2    2     ...      2020-01-23
3    3     ...      2020-01-23
4    4     ...      2020-01-23
5    5     ...      2020-01-23
6    6     ...      2020-01-23
7    7     ...      2020-01-23
8    8     ...      2020-01-23
9    9     ...      2020-01-23
10  10     ...      2020-01-23
```

When I print `df.columns`, it generates `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')`.

Full code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1, 3):
    data = {
      'filter_LIKE_GCMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_JSDWMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_SGDWMC': '',
      'filter_LIKE_BABH': '',
      'currentPage': page,
      'pageSize': '15',
      'OrderByField': '',
      'OrderByDesc': ''
    }

    website_url = requests.post('http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308894', data = data).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090632/python-excel-export
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=0)[0]
    # df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    # df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    # df = df.iloc[1:]
    # print(df.head(5)) 
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
     0     ...               8        ---> row without index to exclude
0   序号     ...          竣工备案日期   ---> row to set as header
1    1     ...      2020-01-23
2    2     ...      2020-01-23
3    3     ...      2020-01-23
4    4     ...      2020-01-23
5    5     ...      2020-01-23
6    6     ...      2020-01-23
7    7     ...      2020-01-23
8    8     ...      2020-01-23
9    9     ...      2020-01-23
10  10     ...      2020-01-23
11  11     ...      2020-01-23
12  12     ...      2020-01-22
13  13     ...      2020-01-22
14  14     ...      2020-01-22
15  15     ...      2020-01-22

[16 rows x 9 columns]
     0     ...               8          ---> row without index to exclude
0   序号     ...          竣工备案日期     ---> row to set as header
1   16     ...      2020-01-22
2   17     ...      2020-01-22
3   18     ...      2020-01-22
4   19     ...      2020-01-22
5   20     ...      2020-01-22
6   21     ...      2020-01-22
7   22     ...      2020-01-22
8   23     ...      2020-01-22
9   24     ...      2020-01-22
10  25     ...      2020-01-22
11  26     ...      2020-01-22
12  27     ...      2020-01-22
13  28     ...      2020-01-22
14  29     ...      2020-01-22
15  30     ...      2020-01-21

[16 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible the best here is set second row to DataFrame columns is method of created DataFrame, here [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=0)[0]
#or
df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=1)[0]
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_html(str(table), header=1)[0]
```

If not possible use solutions above:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

EDIT: Output for `df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=0)[0]` in pandas 0.25.1:

```
   序号                                               工程名称             建设单位  \
0   1                       朝阳区三里屯路19号院9号楼S09-1-局部内外装修工程  北京三里屯南区物业管理有限公司   
1   2  改善办学保障条件-基础设施改造-定额管理项目2-芍药居校区整体改造二期工程2标段（阶梯教室、...           北京服装学院   

  建设单位项目负责人          施工单位 施工单位项目负责人                  编号              备案部门  \
0        冯锐      北京菲尼有限公司       徐广辉  0076朝竣2020(装)0064号  北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会   
1       兰泰黔  北京广佳建设股份有限公司        卿朵  0074朝竣2020(装)0062号  北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会   

       竣工备案日期  
0  2020-01-23  
1  2020-01-23  
   序号                                               工程名称              建设单位  \
0  16                        朝阳区酒仙桥北路甲10号院205号楼1层2层内装修工程  北京美伸医学影像诊断中心有限公司   
1  17  F座办公楼（中关村科技园电子城西区二期A6地块项目）11至12层（电梯楼层12至13层）局部...        鸿合科技股份有限公司   

  建设单位项目负责人            施工单位 施工单位项目负责人                  编号              备案部门  \
0        岳洋  北京朋利嘉业装饰工程有限公司       李宗仓  0063朝竣2020(装)0051号  北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会   
1       刘秀铭   北京盛茂盛建设工程有限公司       李艳华  0064朝竣2020(装)0052号  北京市朝阳区住房和城乡建设委员会   

       竣工备案日期  
0  2020-01-22  
1  2020-01-22
```

Comment: Sorry, this dataframe is read by `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]`, so I assume I can't use `pd.read_csv` at this case.

Comment: Thank you, `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]; df.columns = df.iloc[0]; df = df.iloc[1:]` works just fine.

Comment: Just tried with `skiprows=0; skiprows=1; or header=1`, all not works. ;(

Comment: I add full code, you may test it. I find only `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]; df.columns = df.iloc[0]; df = df.iloc[1:]` works.

Comment: @ahbon - I am a bit confused, your code `df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=0)[0]` working for me perfect.

Comment: I posted the output, could you check if it's same as yours?

Comment: My pandas version is `0.23.4`, I'll try with another version later.