# Iterate all ids and crawler table's elements as dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to click into each item for each page from [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S4iT.jpg), then crawler all infos from [this page](https://www.pudong.gov.cn/shpd/InfoOpen/InfoDetail.aspx?Id=956244) in red circle and save then as dataframe format.

In order to loop all pages, I need to iterate all `Id`s in the second link, but I don't know where I can get them.

```
https://www.pudong.gov.cn/shpd/InfoOpen/InfoDetail.aspx?Id=956244
```

[image]

I starts with the following code but I get a response of no table found which I can visually see from the source code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pudong.gov.cn/shpd/InfoOpen/InfoDetail.aspx?Id=1044647'
website_url = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'ewb-claim table'})
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090632/python-excel-export
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df.head(5))
```

Ouput:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-d95369a5d235>", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 915, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 749, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 385, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

ValueError: No tables found
```

Someone could help? Thanks.

Comment: The data is generated dynamically. There is no data you want in the website_url you get. Try to collect data by rendering.

Comment: Could you provide examples pls?